# unable to use beautifulsoup4 in pycharm 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, pycharm

I'm using pycharm with the interpreter set to 2.7.

I've installed beautifulsoup4 using PyCharm (I just found the package and added it - I did not do this in command line) and if I hover over the package in PyCharm it says it's located in:

```
PycharmProjects/ven/test/lib/Python2.7/site-packages
```

It's version 4.7.0 of beautifulsoup4.  I've also tried to get it to work, using:

```
pip --install upgrade beautifulsoup4
```

When I use:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

It does nothing and returns

```
ImportError: cannot import name beautifulsoup
```

The 'from bs4..' line is also greyed out in the PyCharm script, leading me to believe it's not a valid command.

So, my question is, can I use beautifulsoup4 with the interpreter set to 2.7?  Does everything in my set up seem correct?  Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?  thanks.

Comment: edited question above.

Comment: can you comment the output of sys.version

Answer (score 1):

import  BeautifulSoup like

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 1):

In your question you mention that you have used the statement like

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

But the error you have given is

```
ImportError: cannot import name beautifulsoup
```

Maybe you are doing `from bs4 import beautifulsoup`

It should be 'BeautifulSoup'